# All distinct groups of $C_{13} \rtimes_{h} C_4 $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Describe all homomorphisms $h: C_4 \to Aut(C_{13})$, for each h describe $C_{13} \rtimes_h C_4 $ in terms of generators and relations. How many distinct isomorphism types of groups of the form $C_{13} \rtimes_h C_4 $ are there?

So $C_4=\{1,y,y^2,y^3\}, C_{13=}\{1,x,...,x^{12}\}$, and $Aut(C_{13}) \cong C_{12}$

so $h(y)$ must have orders 1, 2, and 4. These are $\phi_1, \phi_5, \phi_8, \phi_{12}$ (where $\phi_a(x)=x^a$). Call them $h_0, h_1, h_2, h_3$ respectively. I then got:

$C_{13} \rtimes_{h_0} C_4 = C_{13} \times C_4$

$C_{13} \rtimes_{h_1} C_4 = <X,Y| X^{13}=1, Y^4=1, YX=X^5Y>$, with $X=(x,1), Y=(1,y)$

$C_{13} \rtimes_{h_2} C_4 = <X,Y| X^{13}=1, Y^4=1, YX=X^8Y>$

$C_{13} \rtimes_{h_3} C_4 = <X,Y| X^{13}=1, Y^4=1, YX=X^{-1}Y> = D_{26}^*$ (Binary Dihedral group)

So far am I correct?

But I'm not sure about the last part of the question. They all look pretty distinct to me... Are there in fact 4 distinct groups of $C_{13} \rtimes_{h} C_4 $??

Comment: Concerning the last part: the semidirect product is fully determined by a homomorphism $h$, so there should really be 4 isomorphism classes.

Comment: There are in fact five different groups of order $\;52\;$ up to isomorphism, all of which are semidirect products: the two *trivial* ones are in fact *direct* products and thus abelian, and the other three are non-abelian. With cyclic Sylow $\;2$-subgroup there are three different groups up to isomorphism: one abelian, two non-abelian.

Comment: @Timbuc but if I've got 4 groups above, then there's $C_{26} \times C_2$ and $D_{26} \times C_2$. Shouldn't there be 6 groups of order 52??

Comment: @alex Observe that $\;|\phi_5|=|\phi_8|=4\;$ are the two elements of order $\;4\;$ in Aut$(C_{13})\;$ and thus the direct products they determine are isomorphic. You can read in pages 96 and on about this in http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GTe6.pdf

Comment: @Timbuc So to determine the distinct groups up to isomorphism of $C_n \rtimes_h C_m$ I just need to look at those homomorphisms $h$ with distinct orders in $Aut(C_n)$, is that correct?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure that's true in *all* cases  but seems to be true in this particular case. Perhaps Derek can help us out for the general case.

Comment: As I said in my answer below, the isomorphism type is determined by the image of $h$ in ${\rm Aut}(C_n)$, but not necessarily by the order of that image. For example  ${\rm Aut}(C_8) \cong C_2 \times C_2$, so there are three possible images of order $2$, and they result in three non-isomorphic groups $C_8 \rtimes_h C_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third groups on your list are isomorphic. If $YX=X^5Y$, then $Y^{-1}X = X^8Y^{-1}$, so an isomorphism is induced by the map $X \mapsto X$, $Y \mapsto Y^{-1}$.

As a general rule, there is exactly one isomorphism type of semidirect products $C_a \rtimes_{\phi} C_b$ for each possible ${\rm Im}(\phi)$.